# Edit file in-place without modifying line endings

Tags: emacs, git, sed, crlf

I need to modify sources under Git version control. The sources are Visual Studio project files, which makes them native Microsoft. I want to ***avoid*** whitespace issues, including line ending games.

I looked at the files before the modification under emacs, and the ***`^M`*** was clearly not present.

I then executed the following from a script from a Linux machine:

```sh
sed -i 's/odbc32.lib //g' *.vcproj
sed -i 's/odbccp32.lib //g' *.vcproj
```

When I look at the changes:

```diff
$ git diff cryptest.vcproj
diff --git a/cryptest.vcproj b/cryptest.vcproj
index cec447d..9ae71ea 100644
--- a/cryptest.vcproj
+++ b/cryptest.vcproj
@@ -76,7 +76,7 @@
...
Name="VCLinkerTool"
-        AdditionalDependencies="odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib Ws2_32.lib"
+        AdditionalDependencies="Ws2_32.lib"^M
        SuppressStartupBanner="true"
...
```

How do I perform a replacement without adding extraneous whitespace?

Answer (score 1):

These days emacs will automatically detect the line endings used in a file and so you will not see whether a file has `\n` or `\r` or `\r\n` line endings. Any edits in emacs will preserve and imitate the line endings.

To really see what the file has you can try `cat -vet` which shows control chars including `^M`, tabs (`^I`), and the end of line (`$`).

Note that `git` can be configured to automatically convert `\r\n` to `\n` or vice versa when moving text files between the working directory and the object database. See this [article](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/) and this [article](http://adaptivepatchwork.com/2012/03/01/mind-the-end-of-your-line/) to check how your git is configured, globally and per-repository and how you can change it.

It's difficult to see how `sed` could have introduced the `\r`. I'm assuming you are on a Unix system.

---

At the top of your working directory check that the following commands do not show anything:

```
git config core.eol
git config core.autocrlf
find . -name .gitattributes -o -name attributes
```

Run the original unedited file through `cat -vet` and check whether all, some, or none of the
lines end with the 3 characters `^M$`.

Comment: ***"I'm assuming you are on a Unix system..."*** - yes (kind of). I'm on a Linux system, not Unix: *"...I then executed the following from a script from a Linux machine""* .

Comment: To get back to the orginal question: *"How do I perform a replacement without adding extraneous whitespace?"*. I don't think that's provided in your answer.

Comment: At the top of your working directory can you try the following commands:
`git config core.eol`
`git config core.autocrlf`
`find . -name .gitattributes -o -name attributes`
and if they show anything add the results to your question.
Also, does `cat -vet cryptest.vcproj` before the edit show the line endings as 3 chars `^M$` on all lines, only some, or none.